# How do I add a Adobe Typekit font to my Magento shop

Tags: theme, design, font-family

I am wondering how I can get my Typekit font working on my Magento site. Normally it works like this.

HTML markup:

```
<head>
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/oti3nzu.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
```

CSS markup:

```
html, body {
font-family: "niveau-grotesk",sans-serif;
}
```

So to try this with Magento I added the following to my `default_head_blocks.xml` inside `myVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<head>
<link src="https://use.typekit.net/oti3nzu.js"/>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
```

I deployed my static content with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and if I check the sourcecode of my homepage it shows this line:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://localhost:8888/website/shop/pub/static/frontend/myVendor/mytheme/en_US/https://use.typekit.net/oti3nzu.js"></script>
```

But it won't load the `<script>`. I guess I am doing it wrong but also the `src` to that Typekit javascript should be just "https://use.typekit.net/oti3nzu.js" right? I am stuck.